# Unicode is not supporting in vb6

Tags: character-encoding, vb6, multilingual

we have a application written in vb6, we also have the multilingual support for this application, we provide all the user message along with the ID's in .LNG file but application is not supporting the Unicode language like Japanese, Chinese etc.,can anyone suggest how to proceed the minimum change in the code and make this work !!!

Thanks

Comment: This is a hugely open-ended question.  There isn't any single simple thing you can do to magically address this.

Comment: These guys have a couple sets of example code if you read the thread.  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?583958-RESOLVED-Loading-a-unicode-text-file

Comment: @Bob77 can you please suggest some ways of doing it i know this is open ended question, is there a way of doing it apart from using third party controls

Comment: @VincentJames i can see the proper Japanese text when i observe through break points, the problem lies in displaying the string. When the vb6 implicitly converting the Unicode to ASCII for displaying the string is again converting to ASCII which is not suppose to in my case is there a way to suppress this conversion

Comment: @Bob77 i can see the proper Japanese text when i observe through break points, the problem lies in displaying the string. When the vb6 implicitly converting the Unicode to ASCII for displaying the string is again converting to ASCII which is not suppose to in my case is there a way to suppress this conversion

Comment: There is no ASCII involved, but instead localized ANSI or DBCS which isn't the same thing at all.  VB6 isn't doing the conversion though, the ANSI controls you use are doing it.  VB6 comes with only a few Unicode controls.  You might look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242115(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Standard VB6 controls doesn't support UNICODE. It is possible to use MS Forms controls (FM20.DLL). [INFO: Usage and Redistribution of FM20.DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224305).

The problem is that old version i buggy and is updated by MS-Office. New version of office id 64-bit and doesn't contain 32-bit FM20.DLL. I think it it only 'simple' way of implementing UNICODE but still it is massive change to the application.

Howerer VB6 supports different languages at least European, but the texts have to be properly encoded ([Code Page Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I suppose that usual Windows font such as MS-San Serif, Arial supports most of languages.

If the windows default language is set properly other language characters should work. See e.g. [HOW TO:Change language settings in Windows XP](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=5982) or try Japanese windows direclty.

Comment: FM20.dll is a good alternative but it is basically built for MS word applications, my concern is how reliable it is to use in vb6 application i got to now that many compatible issue will arise if we do so. can u please suggest some font that supports all the encodings

Comment: my application support multilingualism, but the problem is that this is the first time we are supporting Unicode, for eg if in the regular PC if i select Japanese language it should support the select language in any PC can u please share some knowledge

Comment: Standard VB6 controls doesn't support unicode. So by my understanding it is either necessary to use unicode controrls(FM20) or proper windows language (maybe you would need japanese windows).